# facebook php api Param "place" must be a valid place tag ID

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, tags

Question is about **tagging other pages** in a video upload via facebook api

I'm trying to create a facebook post via the php API. I'm able to upload videos or photos, but when I want to "tag" (the equivalent of "with") in a post I'm **unable** to...

I'm able to get the place ID via

> [https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=**name_of_place_**&type=place&access_token=***token***](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=__name_of_place___&type=place&access_token=___token___)

```
$videoData = array( 'description' => $facebook_caption, 
                        'source' => $fb->videoToUpload($media_path) , 
                        'title' => $facebook_title,
                        'place' => ['id'=>'place_ID','name'=>'placeName'],
                        'tags' => 'facebookpageuser1,facebookpageuser2'
                       );
    $response = @$fb->post('/me/videos',$videoData,$pageAccessToken);
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

I get an error : "Param place must be a valid place tag ID"

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException: (#100) Param
>   place must be a valid place tag ID in
>   .../vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php
>   on line 115

is someone know how to add a "valid place tage ID" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place tag has no *name* parameter. See in the documentation: [Place Tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place-tag/)
But according to the documentation, the post method uses a parameter referring to Place. There, this parameter occurs - [Place](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place/)
Also note that the correct identifier is a number string.

Solution 1, Try without the name parameter. Maybe the error is in the documentation.:

```
'place' => ['id'=>'place_ID'],
```

Solution 2, I'm not sure if the parameter should be an array (The documentation does not show this). Therefore, if solution 1 does not work, try using json:

```
'place' => json_encode(['id'=>'place_ID']),
```